# Magento Add Attribute Option on adding single option at a time?

Tags: magento-enterprise, php, product-attribute, custom-options

I would think that I would be able to add multiple options through this method, 
but it seems that only a single on is being added? How would I add multiple options?
There are also two things I am uncertain of which is the position and default option, not sure how to get those working?

```
$attributeModel = \Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('frontend_label', 'Color');
$attributeCode  = $attributeModel->getData('attribute_code') [0]['attribute_code'];

$attributeModel = \Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->loadByCode('catalog_product', $attributeCode);

$data = [
    'option' => [
        'value' => [
            0 => [
                0 => 'Red',     // Admin
                1 => 'default', // Default store view
                // position   ???
                // is_default ???
            ],
            1 => [ 0 => 'Blue',  1 => 'default', 2 => 0 ],
            2 => [ 0 => 'Green', 1 => 'default', 2 => 0 ],
        ],
    ],
];

$attributeModel->addData($data)->save();

print_r($attributeModel->getData());
die;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it via the installer script.
The key is to include your own resource setup script.

Adjust the code accordingly to allow yourself to change set the store value.
In my code it is hard coded to store 0.

It should get you along the right track.

In config.xml you will have inside the global tags:

```
<global>
....
....
<resources>
    <yourmodule_yournamespace_setup>
        <setup>
            <module>YourModule_YourNamespace</module>
            <class>YourModule_YourNamespace_Model_Resource_Setup</class>
        </setup>
    </yourmodule_yournamespace_setup>
</resources>
</global>
```

Then create the class `YourModule_YourNamespace_Model_Resource_Setup`

```
class YourModule_YourNamespace_Model_Resource_Setup extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Setup 
{
  /**
     * Create Product attributes for select list
     *
     * @param string $attribute_code
     * @param array $optionsArray
     */
    public function addAttributeOptions($attribute_code, array $optionsArray) 
{
        $tableOptions = $this->getTable('eav_attribute_option');
        $tableOptionValues = $this->getTable('eav_attribute_option_value');
        $attributeId = (int) $this->getAttribute('catalog_product', $attribute_code, 'attribute_id');
        foreach ($optionsArray as $sortOrder => $label) {
            // add option
            $data = array(
                'attribute_id' => $attributeId,
                'sort_order' => $sortOrder,
            );
            $this->getConnection()->insert($tableOptions, $data);

            // add option label
            $optionId = (int) $this->getConnection()->lastInsertId($tableOptions, 'option_id');
            $data = array(
                'option_id' => $optionId,
                'store_id' => 0,
                'value' => $label,
            );
            $this->getConnection()->insert($tableOptionValues, $data);
        }
    } 

}
```

Now in your installer you can do:

```
$data = array('value1','value2','value3');
$installer->addAttributeOptions('<attribute_code>', $data);
```

Hope that helps

Comment: What is actually running this, just next visit to Magento frontend or ... ?

Comment: Generally, yes. If a module's config.xml is of a newer version than is listed in the core_resource table. (this includes the data installs as well) - a better way would to use n98-magerun to initiate setup scripts when site is in maintenance mode. You'b be best to read up on what/how magento's install/setup system works. see : http://inchoo.net/magento/magento-install-install-upgrade-data-and-data-upgrade-scripts/ as a good writeup, and https://wiki.magento.com/display/MAGE2DOC/Installing+and++Upgrading+Modules

Comment: Sorry for the late accept, +1 and accepted

Answer (score 2):

I have found the solution in different way using `installer` script. Create in root `test.php file`.

```
<?php
 error_reporting(E_ALL);
 require_once 'app/Mage.php';
 umask(0);
 echo "<pre>";
 /* not Mage::run(); */
Mage::app();
try
{   
$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

$color = array('Red','Green','Blue','Pink','Yellow','orange');
$iProductEntityTypeId = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getResource()->getTypeId();
$aOption = array();
$aOption['attribute_id'] = $installer->getAttributeId($iProductEntityTypeId, 'color');

for($iCount=0;$iCount<sizeof($color);$iCount++){
   $aOption['value']['option'.$iCount][0] = $color[$iCount];
}
$installer->addAttributeOption($aOption);

$installer->endSetup();   
?>
```

put this and run the script. and check in back-end.

Let me know if any comments.

Comment: How would I use it as an installer script though, I've read about them several times but am not certain how to use them.

Comment: if you don't want to use as script then just follow the step which I have told you

Answer (score 1):

This is working for me, It includes the options but not the default (yet) I'm still looking for the default.  I pass an array of options and the attrib id . this function is called by a cron job.

```
function ambassUpdate($ambassName, $attr_id){
$installer = new Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup('core_setup');
$installer->startSetup();

$aOption = array();
$aOption['attribute_id'] = $attr_id; 

for($iCount=1;$iCount<sizeof($ambassName);$iCount++){
//for($iCount=1;$iCount<4;$iCount++){
    $aOption['value']['option'.$iCount][0] = $ambassName[$iCount];
    $aOption['order']['option'.$iCount] = $iCount + 10;     
}

$installer->addAttributeOption($aOption);
$installer->endSetup();
return true;
```

}